# Numpy- weight and sum rows of a matrix

Tags: python, vector, matrix, numpy

Using Python & Numpy, I would like to:

- Consider each row of an (n columns x
  m rows) matrix as a vector
- Weight each row (scalar
  multiplication on each component of
  the vector)
- Add each row to create a final vector
  (vector addition).

The weights are given in a regular numpy array, n x 1, so that each vector m in the matrix should be multiplied by weight n.

Here's what I've got (with test data; the actual matrix is huge), which is perhaps very un-Numpy and un-Pythonic.  Can anyone do better?  Thanks!

```
import numpy

# test data
mvec1 = numpy.array([1,2,3])
mvec2 = numpy.array([4,5,6])
start_matrix = numpy.matrix([mvec1,mvec2])
weights = numpy.array([0.5,-1])

#computation
wmatrix = [ weights[n]*start_matrix[n] for n in range(len(weights)) ]

vector_answer = [0,0,0]
for x in wmatrix: vector_answer+=x
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even a 'technically' correct answer has been all ready given, I'll give my straightforward answer:

```
from numpy import array, dot
dot(array([0.5, -1]), array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]))
# array([-3.5 -4. -4.5])
```

This one is much more on with the spirit of linear algebra (and as well those three dotted requirements on top of the question).

**Update:**
And this solution is really fast, not marginally, but easily some (10- 15)x faster than all ready proposed one!

Answer (score 8):

It will be more convenient to use a two-dimensional `numpy.array` than a `numpy.matrix` in this case.

```
start_matrix = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
weights = numpy.array([0.5,-1])
final_vector = (start_matrix.T * weights).sum(axis=1)
# array([-3.5, -4. , -4.5])
```

The multiplication operator `*` does the right thing here due to NumPy's broadcasting rules.

Comment: @Sven: All tough correct answer, but your solution will have serious performance penalties with (much) larger entities. Thanks

Comment: @eat: Really?  Do you have some numbers?

Comment: @Sven: yes, really. It of course depends on size and shape of matrices (and hardware). I'll be back with some timings soon, but I'm sure you'll be able to do them yourself. Thanks

Comment: @Sven: For example, when `weights` is 1x2 array and `start_matrix` is 2x1e5, then my solution (in my computer) is some 12 times faster. Thanks

Comment: @eat: Did some measurements: Your solutions seems to be twice as fast as mine.  Does not seem too serious to me.  (Don't get me wrong -- I like your answer.)

Comment: @eat: I used 1e6 x 3, since I expected the vectors themselves to remain small.

Comment: @Sven: No, I don't get you wrong. I think there exist quite a variance of performance difference's depending on hardware, (os), shape and size. And of'course anything significant can be observed only with really much larger arrays. (However I believe that general `numpy` users should be aware of this kind of behavior).

Comment: numpy.array doesn't do proper matrix multiplication. Consider what numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]]) * numpy.array([1,2]) should produce with what actually is computed. Use numpy.matrix instead.

Comment: @Dunes, both solutions proposed do the math correctly as specified in the problem statement.